# How to search a JSON in MySQL dB to satisfy the required condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-5.7

Assume I have a data list in the MySQL dB as below:

```
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | index_date | token_json                                |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  0 | 20200902_0 | [{"tk": [1, 2], "amt": [20, 49]}]         |
|  1 | 20200902_1 | [{"tk": [4, 3], "amt": [10, 39]}          |
|  2 | 20200902_2 | [{"tk": [7, 4], "amt": [12, 29]}          |
|  3 | 20200902_3 | [{"tk": [8, 7, 6], "amt": [13, 19, 19]}   |
|  4 | 20200902_4 | [{"tk": [9, 6], "amt": [25, 59]           |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

The token_json field is actually a JSON string stored. Now, I would like to get the subset of this data with criteria `"sub_token" > 5`.
The output subset should looks like below:

```
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | index_date | token_json                                |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  2 | 20200902_2 | [{"tk": [7, 4], "amt": [12, 29]}          |
|  3 | 20200902_3 | [{"tk": [8, 7, 6], "amt": [13, 19, 19]}   |
|  4 | 20200902_4 | [{"tk": [9, 6], "amt": [25, 59]           |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I try the command below but doesn't work.

```
SELECT * from my_table
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(token_json, '$.tk') > 5;
```

Can anyone guide me how to get such subset?
My MySQL version is 5.7.19-17-57-log

Comment: what's your DB's version ?

Comment: *I try the command below but doesn't work.* JSON_EXTRACT extracts ONE value/array/object from the specified nesting level and path. You have an array of objects - so you must parse the array into separate objects then extract and test names property of each object. Use JSON_TABLE if available on your MySQL version, recursive parsing in CTE, or static parsing based on synthetic numbers-generationg subquery or service table. PS. Specify precise MySQL version - it is critical for your task.

Comment: Why id = 2 is missing in the expected result? first item is tk = 7.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Sorry! My bad. I add id=2 in the subset. It should be there.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan my MySQL version is 5.7.19-17-57-log. I add this information in the description now. Thanks to point this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DB's version is 8+, then you can use `JSON_TABLE()` function as

```
WITH t(arr, id, token_json) AS
(
 SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(token_json, '$[*].tk'), id, token_json FROM my_table t
)
SELECT id, token_json
  FROM t 
 WHERE EXISTS 
 ( SELECT 1
     FROM t AS t2
     JOIN JSON_TABLE( CAST( arr AS JSON ), "$[*]"
             COLUMNS(
                     val INT PATH "$"
             )
          ) js
    WHERE t2.token_json = t.token_json     
      AND val > 5 )
```

**Update** : Considering your DB version is 5.7 , you can use such a method as below :

```
SELECT id, token_json
  FROM my_table
 WHERE id IN
       (SELECT id
          FROM (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(token_json, '$[*].tk'),
                                    CONCAT('$[', i, ']')) AS val,
                       t.*
                  FROM my_table t
                  JOIN (SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i
                         FROM information_schema.tables i
                         JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) AS iter
                        WHERE @i < (SELECT MAX(JSON_LENGTH(token_json))
                                      FROM my_table) - 1) AS t) AS tt
         WHERE val > 5)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e552566c761fa36b6839e96a958185d)</kbd>

**Update 2** : If you converted values into this format(*as mentioned within the last comment*) ;

```
+----+------------+---------------------------------------------+
| id | index_date | token_json                                  |
+----+------------+---------------------------------------------+
|  0 | 20200902_0 | {"tk": [1,2], "amt": [20,49]}               |
|  1 | 20200902_1 | {"tk": [4,3,2], "amt": [10,39,19]}          |
|  2 | 20200902_2 | {"tk": [7,4], "amt": [12,29]}               |
|  3 | 20200902_3 | {"tk": [8,7,6], "amt": [13,19,19]}          |
|  4 | 20200902_4 | {"tk": [9,6], "amt": [25,59]}               |
+----+------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

then you can use( for **5.7** ) :

```
SELECT id, token_json
  FROM my_table
 WHERE id IN
       (SELECT id
          FROM (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(token_json, '$.tk'),
                                    CONCAT('$[', i, ']')) AS elm,
                       t.*
                  FROM my_table t
                  JOIN (SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i
                         FROM information_schema.tables i
                         JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) AS iter
                        WHERE @i < (SELECT MAX(JSON_LENGTH(token_json))
                                      FROM my_table) - 1) AS t) AS tt
         WHERE elm > 5)
```

you can use( for **8.0** ) :

```
WITH t(arr, id, token_json) AS
(
 SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(token_json, '$.tk') AS arr, id, token_json FROM my_table t
)
SELECT id, token_json
  FROM t 
 WHERE EXISTS 
 ( SELECT 1
     FROM t AS t2
     JOIN JSON_TABLE( CAST( arr AS JSON ), "$[*]"
             COLUMNS(
                     val INT PATH "$"
             )
          ) js
    WHERE t2.token_json = t.token_json     
      AND val > 5 )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50a434b174138ee9fcdbc81cc3a9ba02)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry. I forget to mention that my MySQL version is 5.7.19-17-57-log. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi @SamTT , you can check the alternative method out as edited within the answer.

Comment: how should I perform a benchmark with this sql command if I have more than 300 million lines to check?

Comment: seems you'd better to upgrade version 8 in that case @SamTT .

Comment: I use `explain` to see how SQL been executed and you are right. I need to upgrade to ver 8. What if I change my JSON format to `{"tk": [1,2], "amt": [20, 49]}`? Can I use 1D `JSON_EXTRACT` to get the subset?

Comment: yes, you can use also along with that JSON format @SamTT . I've updated the answer.